# getting undefined constant error while using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel

I have been working with Laravel project and I want to implement angular js. It should be in such way that on page load will call a laravel function and its results should be shows into drop-down options(dynamic dropdown).But when i write ng repeat it shows 'Undefined constant' error.

Here is my code

**Laravel controller**

```
function getproducts(){
   $data = DB::table('product as C')->select('C.*','F.name as cName','S.name as scName')->leftjoin('subcategory as S', 'S.id', '=', 'C.scId')->leftjoin('category as F', 'F.id', '=', 'S.cId')->get();

    print_r(json_encode($data));
}
```

**view**

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-change="change()"><option ng-repeat="item in results ">{{item.id}}</option></select>
```

**angular script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('questionCtrl',['$scope', '$http',  function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.result =[];
  $scope.getproducts = function (){
    $http.get('getproducts').then(function (response) {
       $scope.results = JSON.stringify(response.data);
     },function (error) {
       alert(error); 
    })
  }
}]);
```

I'm getting following error

```
"Use of undefined constant item - assumed 'item' (View:purchase.blade.php)"
```

Comment: I think in `$scope.result =[];` you forgot a "s" at the end of `results` so that it's not found on first render before the data arrive

Comment: No need to stringify data, directly use `$scope.results = response.data;`

Comment: @PankajParkar not only it's not needed, but it's probably the cause of the error, as `results` will be a string instead of an object

Comment: @PankajParkar oky ..<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in results"><option value="?" selected="selected"></option><option label="&quot;" value="string:&quot;">"</option><option label="A" value="string:A">A</option><option label="r" value="string:r">r</option><option label="r" value="string:r">r</option><option label="a" value="string:a">a</option><option label="y" value="string:y">y</option><option label="\" value="string:\">\</option>...

each letter of 'array' is iterated

Comment: @Kaddath thank you..i have updated the code ...but that was not the reason

Comment: i got the answer..